# Textarea does not update on props update: using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, textarea

I need to update the default value of a textarea based on props from a parent component. For some reason, it updates when setting the value, but not when setting the defaultValue. Unfortunately, I need the textarea to be editable by a user, so setting value will not suffice.

For example this updates the textarea, but cannot be edited:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class RenderedScript extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.formScript && 
         <textarea value={this.props.formScript}></textarea>}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

This can be edited, but is not updated on a prop change:

```
export default class RenderedScript extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            {this.props.formScript && 
             <textarea defaultValue={this.props.formScript}></textarea>}
          </div>
        )
      }

    }
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lznvmmjjz

Basically the parent is responsible for controlling the value of the child until the child changes its own value - if the parent updates the value, the child's value will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

It normal that the textarea doesn't update on props change as you are settings the defaultValue
You should decide if your component should be controlled or not
For an uncontrolled component, this does the job, you just need to get the value when needed

```js
class RenderedScript extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            {this.props.formScript && 
             <textarea defaultValue={this.props.formScript}></textarea>}
          </div>
        );
    }
 }


ReactDOM.render(<RenderedScript formScript="default" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you need a controlled component, you can handle the value change by setting the onChange listener
Here is an article about [contolled and uncontrolled inputs](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/)